# How can I implement automatic loading for JSON object in android?

Tags: java, android, ajax

I am working on an audio stream android app and I parsed JSON object from a server to a TextView to display 'now Playing'  for the song name and artist. So when the play button is clicked, the song name playing artist is displayed to the user. The problem is that I want this automatically loaded to the app view when JSON URL link is updated from the server. I don't want the user pressing pause and play to update the view from the app. How do I go about this because I don't want the user restarting the service each time a new song isPlaying to get song information.

Comment: I have been trying this for days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either poll server in short intervals to check if song changed or open socket connection to server to make possible server initiating communication to device.

First approach in simplest form is a very bad practice, as it puts strain on both device and server to check it often enough.
However there is different way to use it, called long polling. With this, you send request to the server, and server does not respond immediately, but holds connection open until it has something to say. After getting reply instantaneously new request is created to make sure no delay is made by it.

The best approach is opening a socket connection, but not every server and program support it.

You can try libraries like SignalR (this one is for .NET mostly, but it's the first one that came to my mind) that choose which approach is the best and takes care of holding connection, reconnecting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching this JSON metadata every time the song is played? If so, that doesn't sound like a good idea. The ideal would be to add song metadata when adding a song to the playlist, then either update it periodically (once a couple of days perhaps) and save that information into a SQLite database for later retrieval.

Comment: I implemented a single stream link for the app. So each time an individual song is played, the name of the song is parsed through JSON to a view in the app. I want the view infinitely updated on the view as its updated in the server